# wxPython dirpickerctrl text box appearing over its own browse button

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

My wxPython dirPickerCtrl text box is appearing over the top of its browse button.

My code is:

```
class chooseFolder(wx.DirPickerCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.DirPickerCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

dataFolder = chooseFolder(self, -1, message= 'Choose Folder', pos = (55,24), 
                          style= wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE,
                          size = (250, 25))
```

I have tried applying different sizers in that panel to see if that solves it but to no avail.

I am using wx version 4.0.3

EDIT: Below is a minimal code example to demonstrate the problem I am having, shown in the second picture.

```
import wx
import os

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        chooseFolder(parent=self,
                     pos = (10,100),
                     style= wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE,
                     size = (250, 30))

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

class chooseFolder(wx.DirPickerCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.DirPickerCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    ButtonFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[picture of text box on top of button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5AQj.png)

[EDIT: Picture of output from minimal code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wttox.png)

Comment: Andi, see my edited answer/query and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Edit based on code sample supplied:
I cannot test on Windows but it looks as if it may be a bug (it works on Linux).
Do you get the same result if you don't sub-class `DirPickerCtrl` but use it directly? Like this:

```
import wx

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        chooseFolder = wx.DirPickerCtrl(self.panel, -1, pos = (10,100), path = "",
            style= wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE,
            size = (250, 30))

#        chooseFolder(parent=self,
#            id = -1,
#            pos = (10,100),
#            path = "/home",
#            style= wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE)#,
#            #size = (250, 30))

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()

#class chooseFolder(wx.DirPickerCtrl):
#    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        wx.DirPickerCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    ButtonFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

You mention that you have tried applying sizers to the panel but in the question, there is no reference to a panel at all.
Try playing with the code below and see if it helps.
For simplicity, it relies solely on fixed positions (no sizers).

```
import wx
import os

class ButtonFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.BtnPressHere = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Press Here", pos=(10,10))
        self.BtnPressHere.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPress)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_DIRPICKER_CHANGED, self.DirChange)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        print("Current Dir: ",os.getcwd())

    def OnPress(self,event):
        dataFolder = chooseFolder(parent=self,
             id=-1,
             path='/home',
             message='Choose Folder',
             pos = (10,100),
             style= wx.DIRP_DEFAULT_STYLE|wx.DIRP_CHANGE_DIR,
             size = (250, 30))

    def DirChange(self,event):
        print("Dir changed to: ", event.GetPath())
        print("Checking Current Dir: ",os.getcwd())

class chooseFolder(wx.DirPickerCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.DirPickerCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = wx.App()
    ButtonFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies for not making the panel clear. I am calling this code within the init of a class of panel. I am not sure that this is the right way to do things, so I am happy to take feedback on that. Regarding your solution, when I copy and paste your code above directly into a new script, unfortunately I still get the same behaviour of the text exit obscuring the button. I am on Windows10 if that is a difference worthy of note.

Comment: @Andi Then edit the question and post your code. Otherwise we just have to guess.

Comment: I can confirm that I see the same problem when I do not call the DirPickerControl as a subclass. I used your code directly and got the same edit box over the button as before. Thanks for the suggestion, though

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the `size` given to the constructor. Try setting the height (second parameter of `size`) to `-1` .